# Changing date format from database

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to change the date format before it is displayed with SQL query however the date format is being completely ignored.

my code is

```
$query = "SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT(formatted, '%d/%m/%Y') from movies;";
```

then further down this is my table

```
echo "<table>"

echo "<table border='2'>"
echo "<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>title</th>
<th>date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['formatted'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

this query is working, however the date format is being ignored and just displaying the date in yyyy-mm-dd I want it in DD-MM-YY.

thanks

Comment: As a side note, you really shouldn't be doing the formatting in SQL - leave that to your application layer (or even the client side display layer - have JavaScript do it).  Formats are culture/locale specific, and your db almost certainly doesn't have the relevant information _about the client_ to know how to display it.  For instance, Europeans tend to use MM/DD/YYYY, and if you don't spell it out, they're going to be thinking of the wrong month/day...

Comment: hmm. Valid point! Ill try working towards that instead! appreciate the input!

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias to name your calculated column

```
SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') AS formatted_date
from movies
```

Use a different name than the existing column to differ between the two. Then use

```
echo "<td>" . $row['formatted_date'] . "</td>";
```

to get the formatted one.

Comment: You sorted this issue in 2 minutes, iv been fighting for around  hours!! Appreciate it keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the alias for the formatted datetime column other wise formatted value will not be called in your code

```
SELECT * ,
DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%d/%m/%Y') `datetime`
from movies
```

Comment: I did not down vote it, however i think you might have been down voted due to the ` instead of ' but I understood it. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @user3365549 no bacticks is the standard practice to use in mysql arround db/table/column name

Comment: hmm yes with phpmyAdmin, but if you try with html it fails.

Comment: @user3365549 in php you can access it as `<?php echo $row['datetime']?>` without bacticks and never call with backticks in php its a mysql escape